# Cakephp 2.3: How to not use 'id' as the label of $belongsTo <select> options

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I run into this dilemma a lot with Cakephp, and I'm prettty sure it's a consequence of my not following/understanding a convention somewhere. In any kind of `belongsTo` (hasAnd or otherwise), I generally find that since `id` tends to be the foreign key, it also ends up being what is displayed in dropdown menus, and this is of course semantically useless.

Here's an example of what I've generally done; I'm hoping someone can set me straight: (I'm just making up these tables because they make a good template for the general problem.)

Suppose:

`Users` table has columns `id`|`firstname`|`lastname`

`Accounts` has `id`|`user_id`

*(nothing I'm doing is this simple, but this is the general form of the problem)*

Using `cake bake all`, my `Accounts/add` view builds a dropdown for `user_id` that literally displays ID numbers. I have found a couple of ways around this, but they all involve basically assembling the information myself. I've either done it by building, in the controller, an `$options` array for the `user_id` dropdown of `Accounts/add` like so:

***Controller***

`$users = $this->Account->User->find('list');`

`$options = Set::combine($users, '{n}.User.id', array('{0} {1}', '{n}.User.firstname', '{n}.User.lastname'));`

***View***

`echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array(
                                                          'div' => array( 'id' =>'UserId'),
                                                        'options'=>$options,'type'=>'select'
                                                        ) )."\n\n";`

Or else by:

***Controller***

`$users = $this->Account->User->find('all', array('recursive' => 1) );`

And then parsing the data at the View in almost the same fashion. In either case, I've always had the lingering certainty that I could be building my models in such a way that addresses this—it just seems like too basic a need to have not been addressed by such an extensive framework.

Comment: You need to change the $displayField in you models and that should return the appropriate array with a find('list')

Comment: Hilarious. I knew it would be something this easy. Thank you. Have you any idea what to do about a circumstance like `firstname` and `lastname`? Might I concatenate them with similar ease somehow? I just tried `array('firstname', 'lastname')` to no avail. : /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For single column tables, a simple $displayField = 'column_name' is the answer.

But for concatenations of columns, there's a bit more code involved:

```
public $virtualFields = array("full_name"=>"CONCAT(first_name, ' ' ,last_name)");
public $displayField = 'full_name';
```

If its a really complicated $displayField, an afterFind solution may be necessary, but for most cases this is the solution.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You're a prince, this is perfect. Face-palm Thursday. ;)