# How to get choices of each item in a table in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.3

This is my choices table

```
id | question_id  | content 
 1     1               bee
 2     1               fly
 3     1               dog
 4     2               cat
 5     2               bat
 6     2               wasp
```

and this is my questions table

```
id |   content
 1       question1
 2       item2
```

This is what i did.With this I could display the question with its choices..what I want to do now, is to paginate it,more like 1 question per page.How to do this?Your help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

```
 $options['fields'] = array('questions.id','questions.content');
    $options['joins'] = array(  
            array(
                'table' => 'generated_exam_items',
                'alias' => 'GenExamItems',
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'GenExamItems.generated_examination_id' => 25
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'questions',
                'alias' => 'Questions',
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions' => array(
                     'Questions.id = GenExamItems.questions_id'
                )
            ),

        );
        $options['conditions']=array('GenExamItems.generated_examination_id' => 25,'Question.id=GenExamItems.questions_id');
$question_detail = $this->Question->find('all',$options);
$this->set('questions',$question_detail);
```

Someone please help me.!!I dont how to do it and im stuck in this for almos a week..

Answer (score 0):

you can get using relation ship with each other model

as here i am just adding skeleton code you need to verify it to you actual code with real classname

In `Question` model write this relation

```
class Question extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Choice' => array(
            'className' => 'Choice',
        )
    );
```

And in `Choice` model you can define like

```
class Choice extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'Question';
}
```

And in controller if you want to fetch for speacific Question with its choices you can write query like below

```
 $question_detail = $this->Question->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Question.id' => $question_id)
    ));
```

let me know if i can help you more

Comment: how could i display it in the view?like this...  1.Question1                                                            a.choice1                                                          b.choice2            ....should i use foreach?

Comment: you have to use for loop to display choices

Comment: thanks but im struggling on how to display it in the view...and one more question , i want each of the question to be paginated,more like 1 question per page?thanks for your help

Comment: you can use pagination pas per document link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the correct associations on both models.

I'll show the code for just one question in the view.

- If you use the automagic way [cake provides](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) (read the "Creating form elements" part) 
  In your controller, you have to get the choices

  ```
  $this->set('choices', $this->Question->Choice->find('list', 
                                 array('conditions'=>
                                      array('question_id'=>$your_question_id))));
  ```

  And in your view, you have to do

  ```
  echo $this->Form->input('choice_id', array('type'=>'radio'));
  ```

  That should automatically display the choices as radios (not really sure what type of input you wanted)
- If by some reason the automagic way doesn't work (be sure to check your model's associations if that happens), then you can pass the array of choices (get them as showed before on the controller) and pass it as a parameter

  ```
  echo $this->Form->input('choice_id', array('type'=>'radio', 
                                             'options'=>$choices));
  ```

*Note:* If the radio labels are showing the ids instead of the content, you'll have to change the [displayField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088196/cakephp-2-3-how-to-not-use-id-as-the-label-of-belongsto-select-options/16088394#16088394) of choices.

Comment: i also want to display the question content?

Comment: Do a $this->Question->findById($id) and display the content you want in the view.

Answer (score 0):

This what i did.It returns the question and corresponding choices.I hope I will be able to someone with this.Thank you.

```
public function take($id=null) { 
    $this->request->params['named']['page'] = (isset($this->request->params['page'])) ? $this->request->params['page'] : 1;
    $options['fields'] = array('questions.id','questions.content');
        $options['joins'] = array(  
            array(
                'table' => 'generated_exam_items',
                'alias' => 'GenExamItems',
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'GenExamItems.generated_examination_id' => 40
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'questions',
                'alias' => 'Questions',
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions' => array(
                     'Questions.id = GenExamItems.questions_id'
                )
            ),

        );
        //$options['contains']='Choice';
        $options['conditions']=array('Question.id = GenExamItems.questions_id');
        $options['order']=array('rand(Question.id)');
        $options['limit']=1;
        $this->paginate=$options;
        $data = $this->paginate('Question');
        $this->set('questions',$data);

}
```