# How to paginate in cakephp by using find?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

This is my choices table

```
id | question_id  | content 
1     1               bee
2     1               fly
3     1               dog
4     2               cat
5     2               bat
6     2               wasp
```

and this is my questions table

```
id |   content
 1       question1
 2       item2
```

This is what i did.With this I could display the question with its choices..what I want to do now, is to paginate it,more like 1 question per page.How to do this?Your help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

```
$options['fields'] = array('questions.id','questions.content');
$options['joins'] = array(  
        array(
            'table' => 'generated_exam_items',
            'alias' => 'GenExamItems',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'GenExamItems.generated_examination_id' => 25
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'questions',
            'alias' => 'Questions',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                 'Questions.id = GenExamItems.questions_id'
            )
        ),

    );
    $options['conditions']=array('GenExamItems.generated_examination_id' => 25,'Question.id=GenExamItems.questions_id');
   $question_detail = $this->Question->find('all',$options);
   $this->set('questions',$question_detail);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get choices of each item in a table in cakephp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538412/how-to-get-choices-of-each-item-in-a-table-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->paginate = array(
            'Claim' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Claim.user_id' => $user['User']['id']),
                'fields'=>array('id','description','title','support_count','oppose_count','user_id','created'),
                'limit' => 5,
                'paramType' => 'querystring'
        ));
        $claim = $this->paginate('Claim');
        $this->set('claim',$claim);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to paginate you shouldn't be using a find call but instead use a paginate call, set the options using $this->paginate.

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'generated_exam_items',
            'alias' => 'GeneratedExamItem',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'GeneratedExamItem.generated_examination_id' => 25
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'questions',
            'alias' => 'Question',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Question.id = GeneratedExamItem.question_id'
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'GeneratedExamItem.generated_examination_id' => 25,
        'Question.id = GeneratedExamItem.question_id'
    )
    'fields' => array(
        'Question.id',
        'Question.content'
    ),
);
```

Next just define the results to a variable like such

```
$this->set('questions', $this->paginate());
```

I have changed a couple of your aliases because it's good practice / convention to use the Singular model (i.e. Question) instead of plural (Questions) as an alias. Also, it's good practice to use the full model name (GeneratedExamItem not GenExamItem) but you can change this back if it's to your preference.