# CakePHP Dropdown showing all table items and preselected record

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm new to cakePHP, and looking for some guidance.

I have a database already set up, and a previous php application I have build which I'm looking to re-build/engineer within cake.

I'm looking at three tables: customers, jobs and statuses.  I have written the model/controller/view for editing a job record.  It pulls back values from the customers and jobs tables (using a 'belongsTo' relationship), and I have created a HABTM relationship between jobs & statuses, so that I can pull the status name and display it in the edit view.  So it works to the point that the system will get the status id from the jobs table, and then allow me to display the status name, based on the status_id.

For my database tables, I have:

```
customers
---------
id   |   first_name   |  Surname
 1          Joe            Blogs


jobs
-----------
id   | date       | status_id
 22   2013-08-01       1

statuses
------------
 id   |  description
  1      Quote Sent
  2      Invoice

jobs_statuses
-----------
 id    | job_id   | status_id
 1         22           1
```

So, I can get the jobs view to show "Quote Sent" in a text box but what I really need is to have a dropdown box which shows all the status descriptions from the statuses table, with the current status for the job pre selected.  So here, we would have a dropdown where "Quote Sent" is preselected in the edit view for job 22, and then I want to be able to select "Invoiced" from the dropdown and save the form - which will then update the database accordingly, so when I call job 22 again, it shows the status as "Invoiced".

Obviously there's many more statuses and data etc in the database than this above.

I'm really struggling to understand how I get this to work… :-(  Any help much appreciated.

I'm using cake 2.3.4 with mysql database

Comment: Just wondering; do you need a HABTM relation for the statuses? It seems you want a Job to have a *single* status, and not *multiple statuses* at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a status dropdown like this (I'm going to assume you call this from the jobs controller)

```
$statuses = $this->Job->Status->find('list');
$this->set(compact('statuses'));
```

And in the view

```
echo $this->Form->create();
//etc
echo $this->Form->input('Status');
```

*Mind* the uppercase in the view and the plural in the controller, since that's how it works with HABTM. In the docs, there's a few paragraphs about this [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements) that can guide you (almost all the way down before reaching "FormHelper::inputs").

With that, the selected status should be pre-selected magically. Be sure to change the [displayField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088196/cakephp-2-3-how-to-not-use-id-as-the-label-of-belongsto-select-options/16088394#16088394) of the Status model if the dropdown box is showing ids.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  It looks god so far, so will try it all out.  Thanks again.